Difference in efficiency of isobaric reversible and irreversible process
I know that the efficiency of a process depends on the reversibility of the same process. When the process is reversible, the efficiency is the highest. Although I don't understand how this works for a isobaric process when irreversiblity comes from a finite temperature difference.
Let's say I have a gas at temperature $T_1$, and pressure $p_0$. I want my gas to expand so I want to add heat to my gas. If I bring my gas in contact with all kinds of different thermal reservoirs, with a temperature only slightly higher than the temperature of my gas, we can approximate this as a reversible isobaric process with final temperature $T_2$ and the amount of work being $W = p_0(V_i - V_f)=nR(T_1-T_2)$.
However if I bring my gas in contact with a single thermal reservoir with temperature $T_2$, and I do this in a quasistatic way (for example I use a thermal resistance which decreases the heat transfer rate), I have an irreversible process (the entropy of the universe increases), however I have the same work extracted.
So why is the reversible process more efficient? (I would say both processes have the same input and work output and thus have the same efficiency).

So what is the question.

The former (reversible) process is more "efficient" in the sense that the transferred energy is stored in hotter reservoirs than in the latter case of a single reservoir. This would allow more work to be extracted by a heat engine connected to those reservoirs, if you so chose. Follow me?


So why is the reversible process more efficient? (I would say both
processes have the same input and work output and thus have the same
efficiency).

I'm going to assume you are asking about the effect that the irreversible isobaric process you described would have on the thermal efficiency of a heat engine cycle incorporating that process. Because, if you apply the definition of the thermodynamic efficiency (net work done divided by gross heat added) to a process alone, you get results that would appear to violate the second law (greater than the Carnot efficiency), or otherwise be absurd (greater than 100% efficiency).
That said, the short answer to your question is, it isn’t.
The irreversible isobaric process you described, which involves the same amount of heat input and work output as a reversible isobaric process, would not result in a lower cycle thermal efficiency than the reversible isobaric process. The reason is the process only involves irreversible heat and not irreversible work (e.g., work involving mechanical friction).
Both irreversible work and irreversible heat generate entropy, satisfying the second law.  But in general, only irreversible work effects cycle efficiency. Another example is an irreversible isochoric (constant volume) process. Since it  involves no  boundary work at all it would not affect the efficiency of a cycle .
Hope this helps.

+1: without the cyclic condition, one could say that an adiabatic expansion is the most efficient process in the world, because it realizes work without receiving heat at all, even being irreversible

@Ruffolo very good

@Ruffolo you do have to keep in mind, however, that an irreversible and reversible adiabatic process can’t connect the same two equilibrium states

Thanks for the reply, however in my example I don't create (extra) entropy in the gas.  The change in entropy of my gas is the same for both processes, only the change in entropy of my surroundings differ (in the second situation the entropy of the surroundings decrease less then in the first situation).
I now understand that I should look to cycles, but I still don't understand how the entropy of the surroundings changes the efficiency of my cycle.

@PhysicsEnthusiast  Yes the change in entropy decreases less in the surroundings which is the same as saying the final entropy is will be greater in the surroundings for the irreversible process than the reversible process. That in turn means less heat would be available to do work in a cycle that incorporates the irreversible process.

@PhysicsEnthusiast Upon re-reading your post I apologize because I find I misunderstood your point. This is one of the exceptions to the general result that an irreversible heat engine cycle is less efficient than a reversible one. The other is where the irreversible process part of the cycle is an irreversible isochoric (constant volume) process. I will revise my answer to explain further.

@PhysicsEnthusiast See revisions to my answer.
